# Python: slice and remove in one step

Tags: python, slice

I have a recursive Python function that removes one item from a copy of a list before passing the smaller list to the recursion:

```
B = A[:]
B.remove(C)
Recursion(B)
```

That works fine, but it seems more elegant to do:

```
Recursion(A[:].remove(C))
```

Unfortunately `A[:].remove(C)` yeilds `None`.  (Why?)  Is there an elegant way to do this in one line?

Comment: Why does it seem more elegant to do it in one line?

Comment: "(Why?)" For example, https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-doesn-t-list-sort-return-the-sorted-list This reasoning is consistent across the standard library; methods that modify containers don't also return the container, because it's confusing to have side effects when you're chaining methods.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could do the following using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which creates a new list without the `C` element, that is assuming that there's only one `C` element in `A` - because `remove()` eliminates the first occurrence of the element, whereas the list comprehension removes *all* occurrences:

```
Recursion([x for x in A if x != C])
```

Comment: Creating new objects instead of modifying the existing ones is generally a less error-prone approach particularly when writing recursive algorithms, anyway.